# Reactive Form consisting of multiple components

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Doesnt seem to be any info on this out there so i guess i'll ask here:

I am creating a form in angular, where every input field is followed by radio buttons, which only appear after the user makes any change to the corresponding input field.
My template for a single of such input field to radio combo looks something like this:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">
        <strong>My Title One</strong>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titleone"
            formControlName="titleone" #titleone placeholder="no input yet" (input)="titleoneChanged = true">
        <div *ngIf="titleoneChanged">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="titleoneConfirm" value="Val 1" formControlName="titleoneConfirm">
                Option 1
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="titleoneConfirm" value="Val 2" formControlName="titleoneConfirm">
                Option 2
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="titleoneConfirm" value="Val 3" formControlName="titleoneConfirm">
                Option 3
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this block is repeated about 20 times in my form.

Form TS looks something like this:

```js
export class GiantForm implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    //some more variables, which i can not show

    initForm(){
        if(this.someApiSource === null || this.someApiSource === undefined){
            return;
        }
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            Subform1:this.formBuilder.group({
                firstName:[this.someApiSource.getFirstName()],
                lastName:[this.someApiSource.getLastName()],
            }),
            //some more subforms...
            subFormWithInputAndRadios:this.formBuilder.group({
                titleone:[this.someApiSource.getInfo('titleone')],
                titletwo:[this.someApiSource.getInfo('titletwo')],
                titlethree:[this.someApiSource.getInfo('titlethree')],
                titlefour:[this.someApiSource.getInfo('titlefour')],
                //20 titles...

                titleoneConfrim:[this.someApiSource.getInfo('titleoneConfirm')],
                titletwoConfrim:[this.someApiSource.getInfo('titletwoConfirm')],
                titlethreeConfrim:[this.someApiSource.getInfo('titlethreeConfirm')],
                //20 title confirms...
            })
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I am not too fond with this kind of approach. it doesnt look clean to me at all.

If anyone has a much better solution to this please let me know. for now i need to know, how to change the template to something like this:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">
        <strong>My Title One</strong>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titleone"
            formControlName="titleone" #titleone placeholder="no input yet" (input)="titleoneChanged = true">
        <app-radiobutton-component></app-radiobutton-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

and have the inputs within that new component still apply to the correct formcontrol.

i tried using @Input to pass the form control but it always resulted in some kind of error. for instance:

```html
        <div>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="inputName" value="Val 1" formControlName="inputControl">
                Option 1
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="inputName" value="Val 2" formControlName="inputControl">
                Option 2
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="inputName" value="Val 3" formControlName="inputControl">
                Option 3
            </label>
        </div>
```

inside radiobutton.component.html

and in radiobutton.component.ts

```js
export class RadioButtonComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input() inputName: string;
    @Input() inputControl: FormControl;
    //...
}
```

resulted in some error like formcontrol not found

I appreciate any help i can get. If anyone knows a much better overall solution to the entire form, not just the template part then please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i did some further experimenting and it turns out that you can pass formcontrols as strings to your child components. And the main form group needs to be passed aswell:

In the parent component

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">
        <strong>My Title One</strong>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titleone"
            formControlName="titleone" #titleone placeholder="no input yet" (input)="titleoneChanged = true">
        <app-radiobutton-component [inputName]="'titleoneConfirm'" [inputControl]="'titleoneConfirm'" [form]="'form'"></app-radiobutton-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the child component:

```js
export class RadioButtonComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input() inputName: string;
    @Input() inputControl: string;
    @Input() form: string;
    //...
}
```

```html
        <div [formGroup]="{{form}}">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="{{inputName}}" value="Val 1" formControlName="{{inputControl}}">
                Option 1
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="{{inputName}}" value="Val 2" formControlName="{{inputControl}}">
                Option 2
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="{{inputName}}" value="Val 3" formControlName="{{inputControl}}">
                Option 3
            </label>
        </div>
```

this worked out perfectly in my case. no idea if this is the REAL angular way or not, but it works

Answer (score 0):

1. For the first part: use FormArray. https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray. You can also find a lot of good tutorials on this
2. For the RadioButtonComponent part. To do custom form components in Angular you will need to implement ControlValueAccessor. Check out this https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html#understanding-controlvalueaccessor